# Install vim-latex in windows

Tags: gvim

I'm stalling Vim-latex. I believe I have done steps 1 and 2 on http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download.
How can I do step 3 if I'm using Windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to type `helptags ~/vimfiles/doc` in command-line mode, that is

```
:helptags ~/vimfiles/doc
```

This step will generate help tags (see `:h helptags`) files which allow you to use tag jump (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

## Plugin Manager

Note that plugin manager does this step for you (e.g. [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#about)) and this is also [recommended](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex). For instance, after installing Vundle, you just need to put `Plugin 'vim-latex/vim-latex'` (in the appropriate place) in your `.vimrc` (in your case `_vimrc` or `_gvimrc`).

See the Vundle's wiki for more details to install Vundle under Windows.

P.S. I never use vim under Windows, so I may be wrong.